# Adding a subtitle to the main title

Tags: 7, blocks

My Website name is Subham Soni.

I want to add two more lines below it.

One as "Developer" and then in another line a quote along with the author.

How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: if you wants to add any quote in new line try Slogan option "admin/config/system/site-information" otherwise you need to change in page.tpl.php and page--front.tpl.php file

Comment: @Smalution why don't you put this as an answer? Because it seems it is.

Comment: Regarding the search bar?

Comment: @XXX Please  ask **one** question per question. If this is supposed to be about search bar, remove the subtitle part. If this is supposed to be about subtitle, remove the search bar part from it. You can ask two questions here, you know. Just ask them **as** two questions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Smalution pointed out, this is generally done using the site Slogan option which is set at `/admin/config/system/site-information`.

This is the standard way of doing this but relies on the theme you are using have the line

```
<?php print $site_slogan; ?>
```

Some where in the page.tpl.php

If you are creating your own theme, or hacking some one elses make sure this is in there. But, in some themes (this goes for Garland that ships with D7) you will see something like

```
<?php print $site_name_and_slogan ?>
```

in the page.tpl.

This is because the page template has gone through a preprocess function in the template.php i.e `function garland_preprocess_page(&$vars)` and the slogan has been wrapped with the title and a new variable created :

```
$vars['site_name_and_slogan'] = $site_name_text . ' ' . $slogan_text;
```

So if you can't see `$site_slogan` straight away that's probably why.